# How do I configure the Service Principal credentials expiration on refresh to connect Power BI Sql Azure Data Source?

Tags: powerbi, azure-powershell, powerbi-datasource

I am using Powershell to update credentials on a Power BI datasource based on Sql Azure.

The credentials are that of a Service Principal's, I obtain a Sql access token and submit changes.

The payload lokos like this:

```
$UpdateUserCredential = @{
    credentialDetails = @{
        credentialType = "OAuth2"
        credentials = "{`"credentialData`":[{`"name`":`"accessToken`", `"value`":`"$token`"}]}"
        encryptedConnection = "Encrypted"
        encryptionAlgorithm = "None"
        privacyLevel = "None"
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

The datasource is set to refresh every 10 days. Do I need to update the credentials programmatically when it expires each time - how often does the credential expire?

Is there a better way to retain credentials within Power BI for a datasource connection that can survive future scheduled refreshes without having to re-enter credentials? e.g using basic username password authentication perhaps, as opposed to OAuth?

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73165015

Comment: how did you fix the issue?

Comment: we ended up using another way to manage passwords I have since left the organisation and cannot remember what it was, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert in powerbi, but for the service principal, you could create a secret i.e. credential whose lifetime is as long as possible with powershell [`New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadapplicationpasswordcredential?view=azureadps-2.0), make sure you have installed the [`AzureAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0) powershell module first. (In the portal, at most you can set it with 3 years)

```
Connect-AzureAD
New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -ObjectId <app-registration-object-id> -EndDate ((Get-Date).AddYears(100))
```